# Any way to draw freehand over the Leaflet map?

Tags: canvas, leaflet, draw, konvajs

Can’t seem to find any solution to be able to freely draw (probably using canvas/konva) over the Leaflet map. Existing solutions (like leaflet.freedraw) produce leaflet vector shapes, which is not ideal for my project. Is it at all possible?

Comment: How are you using leaflet? Does it have drag&drop/zoom abilities?

Comment: Yes, a regular leaflet setup, non-geo maps.

Comment: Looking at https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html I see https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/Leaflet.MapPaint . There's also the possibility of using vector drawing, then displaying those in a `L.Canvas` and grab its contents.

Comment: @IvanSanchez yes, this plugin looks as close to what I was looking for as possible. Thanks!

Comment: I'll add that as an answer, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/Leaflet.MapPaint plugin (from the [list of Leaflet plugins](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#edit-geometries) ) allows for bitmap drawing with some different brushes.

Another approach would be to use any Leaflet plugin for drawing vectors in free-hand mode, then moving that vector data into a `L.Canvas` with the desired style, and capturing the contents of the `L.Canvas`' container.